# how to create a sector and check if some point is in it's area?

Tags: java, geometry, gis, latitude-longitude

I am a Java developer from China. I recently encountered a problem. I have two coordinate points, AB, with both longitude and latitude. I also have a wind direction with an azimuth angle of 0 degrees due north. Now I want to point A As the center point, give the point a radius r and a fan angle d. The azimuth angle of the wind direction is the bisector of the fan angle. Then I check whether point b is inside the fan-shaped area. I don’t know much about geography. Is there any class library or Can the tool class help me implement this function? I have some problems with coordinate calculation in my current code. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;


public class PollutionTracingUtil {
    private static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371.009;

    private static final GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

    public static boolean isInSector(
            double lng1, double lat1, double lng2, double lat2,
            double windDirection,
            double distance, double sectorAngle
    ) {
        // 示例数据：点B的经纬度坐标
        Coordinate pointB = new Coordinate(lng2, lat2);
        Coordinate pointA = new Coordinate(lng1, lat1);
        return isInSector(pointA, pointB, windDirection, distance, sectorAngle);
    }


    public static boolean isInSector(Coordinate pointA, Coordinate pointB, double windDirection,
                                     double distance, double sectorAngle) {
        Polygon sectorPolygon = createSectorPolygon(pointA, distance, windDirection, sectorAngle);
        // 判断点B是否在扇形范围内
        return sectorPolygon.contains(geometryFactory.createPoint(pointB));
    }


    private static Polygon createSectorPolygon(Coordinate center, double distance,
                                               double direction, double sectorAngle) {
        // 扇形的顶点坐标
        // 计算扇形的起始角度和终止角度
        double startAngle = normalizeAngle(direction - sectorAngle / 2);
        double endAngle = normalizeAngle(direction + sectorAngle / 2);
        System.out.println(sectorAngle);
        System.out.println(endAngle);
        // 计算扇形的顶点坐标
        Coordinate[] sectorVertices = calculateSectorVertices(center, distance, startAngle, endAngle);

        System.out.println(startAngle);
        System.out.println(endAngle);
        // 扇形的起始点
        sectorVertices[0] = center;
        sectorVertices[1] = calculateVertex(center, distance, startAngle);
        // 扇形的终止点
        sectorVertices[2] = calculateVertex(center, distance, endAngle);
        sectorVertices[3] = center;
        // 创建扇形范围的多边形对象

        // 打印扇形的顶点坐标
        for (Coordinate vertex : sectorVertices) {
            System.out.println("Vertex: " + vertex.x + ", " + vertex.y);
        }
        return geometryFactory.createPolygon(sectorVertices);
    }

    private static double normalizeAngle(double angle) {
        // 角度归一化至 0 到 360 度之间
        return (angle % 360 + 360) % 360;
    }

    private static Coordinate[] calculateSectorVertices(Coordinate center, double radius,
                                                        double startAngle, double endAngle) {
        // 扇形的起始点
        Coordinate startVertex = calculateVertex(center, radius, startAngle);
        // 扇形的终止点
        Coordinate endVertex = calculateVertex(center, radius, endAngle);
        // todo error in calculate startVertex and endVertex =
        return new Coordinate[]{center, startVertex, endVertex, center};
    }

    private static Coordinate calculateVertex(Coordinate center, double radius, double angle) {
        double longitude = calculateEndpointLongitude(center.getX(), angle, radius);
        double latitude = calculateEndpointLatitude(center.getY(), angle, radius);
        System.out.println(longitude);
        System.out.println(latitude);
        return new Coordinate(longitude, latitude);
    }


    private static double calculateEndpointLatitude(double latitude, double azimuth, double distance) {
        // Convert the latitude to radians.
        double latitudeRadians = latitude * Math.PI / 180;

        // Convert the azimuth to radians.
        double azimuthRadians = azimuth * Math.PI / 180;

        // Calculate the endpoint latitude.
        return Math.asin(Math.sin(latitudeRadians) * Math.cos(distance / EARTH_RADIUS) + Math.cos(latitudeRadians) * Math.sin(distance / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.cos(azimuthRadians));
    }

    private static double calculateEndpointLongitude(double longitude, double azimuth, double distance) {
        // Convert the longitude to radians.
        double longitudeRadians = longitude * Math.PI / 180;

        // Convert the azimuth to radians.
        double azimuthRadians = azimuth * Math.PI / 180;

        // Calculate the endpoint longitude.
        return longitudeRadians + distance * Math.cos(azimuthRadians) / EARTH_RADIUS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double lng1 = 114.5470250;
        double lat1 = 38.0377410;
        double lng2 = 114.6317360;
        double lat2 = 38.0776860;
        boolean inSector = isInSector(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2, 0, 1, 90);
        System.out.println(inSector);
    }
}
```

i tried with chatgpt , the above code still not work; i want a correct longtitude and latitude

Comment: Check that angle between azimuth A-B and central (wind) direction is smaller than d/2